# Implementing an alphabet in C++

Tags: c++, alphabet

I'm making a code for cipher that reads alphabet in it's binary code. Is there a way to implement custom alphabet (not using ASCII)? For example alphabet={a,b,c,d,e,...,z,],[,.,..., ,-} and for each character there's a number 0,1,...,63. So, the bijetion will be from element of alphabet to 6 bit number.

How to make this implementation using simple functions in C++? I tried to make a strings length 1 and corresponding number using if statements and then plug them into .txt file, but it didn't work out.

```
string str1, ..., str63;
string sometext;
str1 = 'a';

// ...

cin >> sometext;
int k;
k = sometext.length();
string res;
ofstream out;
out.open("cipher.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
  res = sometext.substr(i, 1);
  if (res == str1) {
    res = '000000';
  }

  // ...

  if (res == str63) {
    res = '111111';
  }
  out << res;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Having N nearly identical variables is usually a sign you need an array or some other sort of container structure.

Comment: `'000000'` is not a string as you thought. The compiler will warn you about that. Always enable all warnings and read them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a simple class Alphabet achieving your task. It uses [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to store mapping between characters and binary representation, and uses this mapping to convert between those two representations. Also it computes binary representation. Class can be given any alphabet.

For testing I do two conversions between char and binary and output results to console. If requested values are out of range then std::exception is thrown.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVTBbtswDL37KzgPaGykzuIM2CFOM2zF/qC3oghkWW5U2JIhy2u2It@eUZIdK03abTokBvn0yEdSpE2T0IqIx8PhIxe06goGq1YrLh7XwWjphFQFU6zY1KTxHbQmeusbWl2wHWWN9o1cIiUj9ToIMFjbwreq2ZKcaXgJmi6vOF0GgGcwR8iyXLo0gErRariCDd0S1cYWaM4SrCHq7Ug1eFr@m200iK7e5Fy3cAOWjzJeOeZKPrqPmuwih47S@NoRzowhiuMxkjmf4HhzEUMCKUu@xNkRUkoFPRNwDDjP8G91QpjBdMr9NG2qntCci@zEaUkbrQpelsj7hLxHTZhBhpa1DZUkT6fZmoN0ML3BNK4gSmG1gqcYvkKYhli5cB6ehqKL/N4me88fHjDOWS75gt6j0fgG3AjYB@Ovr@hOfuciMnigcd/IUT/ptASuDeMin5VcFBH1SspLiIzXuRl6X7VEb5V8dvFUJzSv2YYpJVUU3mJEQjVTMAlhelYZL8UovTapTSGcgJDYOwGkH8IPoZeMYrpTArNN1i1DIUXmSbYC76SJenFysW7vqcfSOvUGd0m/AfyXfqw6Ub@seDcGRh5vQXYaZAkK3zv7d3mXJN3ap3euqieyIzJwNIr/JJotz8lGlDWfbJmV8V77@LUZhDfhHtA95LWpWxbssyDgQkNNcBSH56exOmPSx21kWh@FJKcFK1/26eKzXyO3Q0wJ8S0Z5MyN96ScxMZk/dimKjPod6/ZSQnn8zQNX11959pQ8sv4vvDzvuhAiaZbcOPoFjKX4tg@tjvZl36s8MeAxjVhDGw3e94S/bfISTr0ex8cDn8A)

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class Alphabet {
public:
    Alphabet(std::string const & _chars)
        : chars(_chars) {
        size_t num_bits = std::ceil(std::log(std::max(size_t(1), chars.size()))
            / std::log(2) - 1e-6);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < chars.size(); ++i) {
            std::string bin;
            for (ptrdiff_t j = num_bits - 1; j >= 0; --j)
                bin += i & (1 << j) ? "1" : "0";
            c2b[chars[i]] = bin;
            b2c[bin] = chars[i];
        }
    }
    std::string ToBin(char c) const {
        auto it = c2b.find(c);
        if (it == c2b.end())
            throw std::runtime_error("Character '" +
                std::string(1, c) + "' not in alphabet!");
        return it->second;
    }
    char ToChar(std::string const & bin) const {
        auto it = b2c.find(bin);
        if (it == b2c.end())
            throw std::runtime_error("Binary '" + bin + "' is out of range!");
        return it->second;
    }
    std::string const & Chars() const {
        return chars;
    }
private:
    std::string chars;
    std::unordered_map<char, std::string> c2b;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, char> b2c;
};

int main() {
    try {
        Alphabet alph("abcdef{}123");
        std::cout << alph.ToBin('f') << std::endl;    
        std::cout << alph.ToChar("0011") << std::endl;
        std::cout << alph.Chars() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0101
d
abcdef{}123
```